# How to get messege from server with less data usage in Android?

Tags: php, android, sockets, server

I am writing a Android program that get message from server. I can refresh my program every second to get message from server, but I don't want to do this work.

Is it possible to send message from server to client IP and then get message with my Android program (that installed in client device)?.

If it is not possible, please say me way to get message from server.

Comment: As far I understand, you can get information from server into android app , that data you recevied can be in JSON or XML format (more option will be there) ,just store that data after fetching into SQLite datbase in your phone so you don't have to request data again and again as it will drain your battery faster

Comment: You cannot actively send a message from the server to the client (android), since the clients ip address is unknown and changing. It is always the client that has to initiate the request/communication. That is why they are called client and server.

Comment: Thank you.but my app is a news app and must be update and has to refresh when server update

Comment: It means i had to refresh my app every time?

Comment: you can use Push notification to alert your app that it can refresh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this

1) Use push Notification in your app

2) When user click notification refresh your app (make a http request to your server fetch the update info).

**OR**

If you don't want to show notification in mobile which is no harm (almost every news app does this). Just don't create notification refresh you app.

for more information refer this

[GCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/)

[pushnotification in android](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)